# Handling data existence validation in ExpressJS service layer or controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a medium-sized website and I figured that I need to write more maintainable code with better project structure.

I found [this article](https://softwareontheroad.com/ideal-nodejs-project-structure/#service) and a few others describing basically the same idea about 3-layer architecture

I find it great as I wasn't using the service layer before and It helped to DRY the code
but the article doesn't include anything about validation and how it should be handled. especially when validation is done against database (like checking resource  existence)

Should I do the validation in the service layer or write validation middleware (which will need to access database and I think this is against the pattern described)

for example, I ended up with two API endpoints where website users update and remove their already added `DeliveryAdddress`. As you can see below validation in the service layer led to routes having duplicated code to handling HTTP response.

my routes files

```js
router.put('/delivery-addresse/:id', DeliveryAddressesController.update);
router.delete('/delivery-addresses/:id', DeliveryAddressesController.remove);
```

`DeliveryAddressesController`

```js
    async update(req, res){
        try {
            ....
            await AddressesService.updateDeliveryAddress(userId, address);
            ....
        } catch(error){
            
            if (error instanceof ValidationError){
                if (error.name === 'NO_SUCH_ADDRESS'){
                    return res.status(404).json(error);
                }
            }
            ....
        }
    },

    async remove(req, res){
        try {
            ...
            await AddressesService.removeDeliveryAddress(userId, addressId);
            ....
        } catch(error){

            if (error instanceof ValidationError){
                if (error.name === 'NO_SUCH_ADDRESS'){
                    return res.status(404).json(error);
                }
            }
            ....
        }
    },
```

### Options

I could think of these options but not sure if they're good and which one.

1. Validation middleware before the controller which (the middleware) itself will call the
   validation method in the service.

   I think it's a good option but, maybe I
   will end up with multiple database calls to fetch the resource if I don't store the result
   in the `req` object
2. Using a function in the catch block to check for any `ValidationError`s and respond but it's not a great readable way.

Comment: I think this second option implementation is good,,its ok if not great readable, but your are saving a request in db, because when you define middleware for checking that record is already available or not if available then you are going to do another actions, its taking more load in your server,, you can use middleware for field validations like  if you are validating fields like userID, addressId is required  and it must be mongo id, so these actions you can include in your middleware,,,,,

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I do already use middleware to check required fields and fields' validity, I didn't include that part for clarity .

Answer (score 0):

The first question you need to ask is what credentials I should write for ... The middleware layer is between the two layers of operation and application, and it is very important what kind of validation you want to do ... For example, if you want two communication services on a network, Establish a key for it and you need a validator to check every key in each service. In this case, it is better to send this key in the header and validate it in middleware, but sometimes you want to evaluate information from other services or even from the database, which requires several validation steps. It is better to implement them all in your services layer! I suggest option 2 for this